# -read_only_relocs and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

Tags: ios

-read_only_relocs and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together 
[image]

hope someone can help me ;-(